# Prevent a VS solution's project from being built by Appveyor

Tags: appveyor

The `.sln` file in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/zspitz/StringAsSql) has two projects -- a class library project, and a tests project. I only want AppVeyor to build the library project, because the tests project requires the Microsoft Access database engine to be installed.

I am using `appveyor.yaml`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of possible options here.

To disable tests, set the following in `appveyor.yml`:

```
tests: off
```

Or create a special build configuration (via the Visual Studio **Configuration Manager...**), say `ReleaseCI`, and specify the configuration in `appveyor.yml`:

```
configuration: ReleaseCI
```

Another option is to create multiple solution files; the UI for switching solutions is simpler (**Solution Explorer** -> **Switch views...**) than the UI for switching build configurations. To specify which `.sln` file should be passed to MSBuild:

```
build:
    project: MySolution.sln
```

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Comment: @britzkopf The original question was _"How can I prevent AppVeyor from building one of my projects?"_ and the answer is _"Create a build configuration specifically for AppVeyor to use, which doesn't build that project; then configure `appveyor.yml` to use that build configuration instead of the standard `Debug` or `Release`"_. How does this not answer the question?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "....in which the tests project is not built" part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch from automatic `msbuild` mode to `script` mode, by adding a `build_script` section to your yaml config file. This might look something like this...

```
build_script:
  - msbuild StringAsSql/StringAsSql.csproj /logger:"C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Appveyor.MSBuildLogger.dll"
```

It's the same command AppVeyor would run automatically on your solution file.